# How to customize jasper elements to print given number of times in single document?

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, barcode

I'm developing a system which contain a *barcode generator* which print barcode(size : 2" x 1") in an A4 sheet. User should be able to print given number of codes in a single A4 sheet (maximum : 3 in a row and 8 in a column).
How to perform this using java or jasper ?

Comment: This question is to broad (you need to show at what point you are, what is current java code, jrxml ecc?) and unclear (what type of barcode?). Please improve your question [edit] it.

Answer (score 0):

of course i can do it by using **DETAIL BAND**...!